# Can fitnesse validate non-xml output

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I am using Rest Fixture with Fitnesse to make a GET request to url which returns non-xml response. Is there a way I could verify text/string (without xpath) in the content returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution.
TEXT is a supported content handler along XML and JSON. It is possible to override the content handler as TEXT and expect the content. Regular expression can also be used to expect content.

```
| Table:smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture.RestFixtureConfig | overridesContentHandlerConfig|
| restfixture.content.handlers.map | application/smil=TEXT |
!| Table:smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture.RestFixture | ${host} ||overridesContentHandlerConfig |
| GET | www.someurl.com | 200 | | [\s\w\d<>/=\:'.]*stringtoverify[\s\w\d<>/=\:'.]* |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fit mode + NetRunner plugin (for .Net).

See [here](https://github.com/imanushin/NetRunner/wiki/Parsing) example, how to parse input line to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use Custom Comparators. This gives you more flexibility on customizing validation on custom/complicated results.

To use custom comparators:
documented [here](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.ConfigurationFile) (search for 'CustomComparators')

> required property: `CustomComparators = <prefix:classname>[,<prefix:class name>]`
>
> motivation: The Slim protocol is all String values. It means that
>   comparison of an expected and actual result for complex datatypes is
>   limited to String equality or Regular Expression matching. If that is
>   not sufficient, a Custom Comparator can do more sophisticated
>   comparisons. Once registered, a Custom Comparator is triggered by its
>   prefix, followed by a colon, in front of the expected value.
>
> Example Comparator implementation:
>
> ```
> public class JSONAssertComparator implements CustomComparator {
>     @Override   
>     public boolean matches(String actual, String expected) {
>         try {
>             JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, actual, false);
>             return true;
>         } catch (JSONException e) {
>             throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Example plugins.properties:
>
> ```
> CustomComparators = json:com.acme.JSONAssertComparator
> ```
>
> Example ScriptTable usage:
>
> ```
> |script|Customer                                | 
> |check|get|cust1|json:{id:cust1,name:"John Doe"}|
> ```